# what is the use of <html:html in struts?

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts, struts-1

what is the use of `<html:html` in struts?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there would be no difference if you use `<html>` instead of plain `<html:html>`.
However, if you use some attributes of `<html:html>` tag, I think the difference will
come out. Suppose you have a usage like `<html:html xhtml="true">`. With this tag all 
other html taglib tags render themselves as XHTML tags.